# How can you filter a data-list to render into multiple outlets in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

How can you filter a data-list to render into multiple outlets in emberjs.
What I have now in not really working, but may help you understand what I want to achieve.

I can solve this by making multiple file-list.hbs template-files ( where I change file in the each to fileList1 or fileList2, ...), but that doesn't seem right.

**What I want to achieve**

I have a documents page where I want to list all of the document in the file list (see fixtures file). But instead of printing out one files-list, I want to split the lists so I have multiple lists according to the filter.

Please look at the code to understand it better ^^
Can anyone help? :)

**File.FIXTURES**

```
App.File.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    showHomepage: false,
    filter: 'filter1',
    url: '/file1.pdf',
    description: 'file1'
},
{
    id: 2,
    showHomepage: false,
    filter: 'filter2',
    url: '/file2.pdf',
    description: 'file2'
},
{
    id: 3,
    showHomepage: true,
    filter: 'filter2',
    url: '/file3.pdf',
    description: 'file3'
},
{
    id: 4,
    showHomepage: true,
    filter: 'filter3',
    url: '/file4.pdf',
    description: 'file4'
}
```

];

**Route**

```
App.InfoDocumentenRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    var store = this.store;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        fileList1: store.find('file' , { filter: "filter1" }),
        fileList2: store.find('file' , { filter: "filter2" }),
        fileList3: store.find('file' , { filter: "filter3" })
    });
},
renderTemplate: function() {

    this.render('file-list', {          // the template to render
        into:'info.documenten',         // the route to render into
        outlet: 'file-list-filter1',    // the name of the outlet in the route's template
        controller: 'file'              // the controller to use for the template
    });

    this.render('file-list', {          // the template to render
        into:'info.documenten',         // the route to render into
        outlet: 'file-list-filter2',    // the name of the outlet in the route's template
        controller: 'file'              // the controller to use for the template
    });

    this.render('file-list', {          // the template to render
        into:'info.documenten',         // the route to render into
        outlet: 'file-list-filter3',    // the name of the outlet in the route's template
        controller: 'file'              // the controller to use for the template
    });
}
```

});

**info/documents.hbs**

```
{{ outlet file-list-filter1 }}
{{ outlet file-list-filter2 }}
{{ outlet file-list-filter3 }}
```

**file-list.hbs**

```
<ul class="download-list">
{{#each file in file}}
<li class="download-list__item">
    <a {{bind-attr href=file.url}} target="_blank" class="download-list__link">
        <i class="icon-download download-list__link__icon"></i>
        {{file.description}}
    </a>
</li>
{{else}}
<li>
    Geen documenten beschikbaar.
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to populate multiple outlets in this way?  Can you describe your requirements a bit more?  It seems to me there may be a much more efficient way to get your desired end result.

Comment: @gravityplanx Ok, added some more explanation... Hope this makes it clearer. Yes, I have a strong feeling there should be an more efficient way, but can't seem to find it yet.. Fairly new to emberjs

Comment: Have you tried simply doing a nested `{{#each}}` within your file-list.hbs?  Something like:  `{{#each file-list in model}} {{#each file in file-list}}` (be sure to store the data within an array on your model in order for this to work).

Comment: I don't quite understand I think... But I also use this file-list.hbs for the homepage, where I just filter the list on showHomepage en not on the other filter property.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about this would be to declare your file-list.hbs as a partial and include it within your other templates where needed as: `{{partial "file-list"}}`.  In your showHomepage where you only want to use it a single time, merely include the `{{partial "file-list"}}` within your showHomepage.hbs.

Then, for your `InfoDocumentRoute`, put the following to declare your model as an array of filelists:

```
App.InfoDocumentenRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var store = this.store;
        return [ 
            store.find('file' , { filter: "filter1" }),
            store.find('file' , { filter: "filter2" }),
            store.find('file' , { filter: "filter3" })
        ];
    }
});
```

And your InfoDocument.hbs as:

```
{{#each file in model}}
    {{partial "file-list"}}
{{/each}}
```

Which will then render the file-list template for each item in the model array.

[More info about partials](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/)

Answer (score 0):

So from what i gather about your question you want to filter your model on your filter property on the model. I am sure there are a few ways to accomplish this but here is another possible solution that could spark another solution.

So in the route I returned the models. Then in the controller I created properties that are filtering the array of models from the route. Then in the template I loop over the array that filter property gives me in the controller and output in the template.

Heres JSBin. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vunugida/5/edit

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   return this.store.findAll('File');
}
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  filter1: function() {
    return this.filter(function(item) {
        return item.get('filter') === "filter1";
    });
  }.property(),

  filter2: function() {
  return this.filter(function(item) {
        return item.get('filter') === "filter2";
      });
  }.property(),

  filter3: function() { 
    return this.filter(function(item){
      return item.get('filter') === "filter3";
   });
  }.property()
  });
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h1>Index Template</h1>

  <ul>
    {{#each}}
      <li>{{url}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

  <p>Filter 1</p>
    {{#each filter1}}
      <li>{{url}}</li>
    {{/each}}

  <p>Filter 2</p>
    {{#each filter2}}
      <li>{{url}}</li>
    {{/each}}

  <p>Filter 3</p>
    {{#each filter3}}
      <li>{{url}}</li>
    {{/each}}

  </script>
```